# How do I generate the DDL file need for Azure Synapse Pathways

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to recreate an Azure SQL database in Azure Synapse. To this end I use SSMS to generate the various create tables script, then use the "Azure Synapse Pathways" tool to convert that script to a Synapse compatible script, but this unfortunately results in many errors and the resultant scripts are unusable. The errors are many and varied, but for example:

TEXTIMAGE ON not supported
CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY not supported
CHECK constraint not supported
FOREIGN KEY not supported

Is there a way to generate DDL file, such that Azure Synapse Pathway has a better chance of converting the script?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this recently and used Visual Studio Database projects to aid the conversion.  Do the following steps in Visual Studio 2019:

1. create a new SQL Server Database project

[image: SQL Server Database project]

2. set the Target platform to 'Microsoft Azure SQL Database' in the project properties

[image: Target platform]

3. Import the database to the project.  Follow the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/import-into-a-database-project?view=sql-server-ver15)
4. Fix any errors that are reported
5. Change the target platform to 'Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse'
6. Fix any errors that are reported.  Dedicated SQL pools only supports `NONCLUSTERED` and `NOT ENFORCED` primary keys for example
7. Publish your project to the target Synapse server
8. I ended up re-importing the database to a new database project for a 'clean' schema.  YMMV

You can also script out SQL from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) in a dedicate SQL pool format or look at command-line tools like [mssql-scripter](https://www.sqlshack.com/all-about-mssql-scripter-the-sql-server-cross-platform-scripting-tool/) and [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15) command line.
Pathway is in preview and I just had too many issues with it.

Comment: Will give it a go thanks

Comment: How are you getting on with this?

Comment: Ahh, TBH I gave up and did it manually. Just used SSMS to create the initial set and then a lot of regex replaces etc.. to strip it down.

Comment: Dude, Visual Studio Database projects is the way to go.  Once you have proper dependency checking, easy refactoring, compile-time error reporting and automated deployments, you won't wanna go back : )

Comment: You can ask SSMS to generate scripts in a dedicated SQL pool-friendly manner by setting the Advanced option 'Script for database engine edition' to 'Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse Edition', but one for next time.  Good luck in your journey.